# using git on local dev env. without pushing

Tags: git

Just started to use git and I'm wondering can I use git on my local dev machine without pusing to the github.com account. I want to track source with commiting them but now pushing to the remote.

As far as I know I'm going to have all features since tracking is used with commited files and pushing only send files to the origin (remote server). Is this right ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`commit` and `push` are different actions.  `commit` work locally and does not touch the remote repository.  If you do not want your local commits pushed, do **not** run `git push` until you are confident of your changes.

You might want to create a local branch and work on that.  I would recommend you to read "[A successful Git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)" to get some ideas.